# Password storage in 1password and other similar password storing applications

Tags: passwords, memory

My understanding of memory in a computer is that it is stored in blocks that are over written only when the computer finds it convenient. so if a program asks to write in a certain block rather than clearing that block, which takes time, the computer will just redefine where that block is so that it can use an empty block and worry about clearing other blocks latter. This is fine but with password storage that means (if I understand correctly) that even though a password may be stored in encrypted form, a non-encrypted form of the password is lying around somewhere in the "uncleared" part of my computers memory.

Please explain to me either why this is not the case or why this is not a security issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If someone has enough access to your device to read the uncleared memory, you've lost anyway.

Comment: it _is_ an issue, many attacks are based on this; freeze spray, firewire DMA, malicious HD firmware, etc

Comment: If this is an issue then how do secure applications that hold sensitive data handle this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the program will only store the plain text password in RAM (Random Access Memory). From this, it will then encrypt it, usually with AES, and write it to the permanent storage.

RAM memory is not permanent, as soon as the power of the computer goes out, the entire RAM is cleared. Meaning that even if it was not written over as soon as the power is out, it is completely gone.

It can also be assumed that the program will take steps to write over the RAM address with null data. But this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

RAM, while stored in "blocks" for virtual memory purposes, is really just a chaotic storage area of random bits of data for applications. In fact, the data in memory can be moved around several places without the program even knowing about it. For example, it might end up moving to a different bank, or stored to the hard drive, or a flash drive, or (as of Windows 10) even be compressed to save space in RAM for active programs.

Ideally, a password manager should store those passwords in memory in the same format as they are on disk, encrypted, and only decrypt them long enough to fill out the relevant form or password box, and then zero out that memory. I'm not sure which memory managers are that paranoid, if any, but it's certainly possible to minimize the risk associated with logical access to the entirety of the computer's memory (although, at that point, you probably have bigger concerns than a password leak).